# How to format the various types of custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, validation, formatting

So i am ready to throw in my custom post type a bunch of custom fields.

All these fields need specific handling for their input and validation.

Exmaples:

- Numeric fields
- E-mails
- WYSIWYG editor
- Datepicker
  e.t.c

I know i can install Types or ACF and get going but i want to know how to code the above.

I have been searching for a "wordpress-way" of doing this but i cant find any.

Looking at the `wp enqueue script` documentation i saw the default libraries that are included out of the box in WP and i saw Jquery UI.

So i wonder, How i would format and validate my custom fields manually?

1. Add inline styles from a UI library like Jquery
2. And include jquery validation to handle my validation

Is this the preferred way and best practice or am i missing something here?

Comment: You can do it with jquery before the information is submitted to the database, or you can do it with php, on save,  when the user clicks on publish/update.

Comment: And about formatting the display for these fields.Mannually with jquery ui?